# Explain Java Notation 'new' with bracketed code

Tags: java, android

I see this notation, a new operator with a class name and then bracketed code, occasionally in Android examples.  Can someone explain this?  In the example below, *PanChangeListener* is a class (or maybe an interface) and 'new' creates an instance, but what role does the bracketed code play with respect to the *PanChangeListener*?

```
fType pcListener = new PanChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onPan(GeoPoint old, GeoPoint current) {
                         //TODO
      }
});
```

Even a name for this syntax would be useful, as I could Google it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

The syntax allows you to create a new class, provide an implementation for some methods, then instantiate it.

> When a local class is used only once, consider using anonymous class syntax, which places the definition and use of the class in exactly the same place.

It works in a similar way to the following code that doesn't use an anonymous class:

```
class MyPanChangeListener implements PanChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onPan(GeoPoint old, GeoPoint current) {
        //TODO
    }
}

// ...

fType pcListener = new MyPanChangeListener();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the creation of an *anonymous class* here. It is creating either (a) an implementation of an interface named `PanChangeListener` or (b) a subclass of an abstract class of that name.

Comment: It is still completely legal if PanChangeListener is an ordinary fully defined class, just uncommon (outside of jUnits anyway... :) ).

Comment: @Affe - As long as the ordinary fully defined class is not final.